# How can We Create delegate for Normal Class in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, delegates

This is my class so want to create the delegate for this.

```
class AClass{

    func doSomthing(){

        print("AClass Method")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func didTapButton()
}

class MyCell {

    var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

    func buttonTapAction() {
        delegate?.didTapButton()
    }
}

class ViewController: MyCellDelegate {

    func didTapButton() {
        print("hello world")
    } 

}
```